# Router TP-Link WR841ND rapidly decreased the speed - How to fix it?

Tags: router, speed

I bought a new router because:

1. my old one (Tenda W311R+) started to behave strangely -> just haven't shown the WiFi  .. times to times, it appeared, but disappeared in a second .. it started with occasional disappearing, but now it's like missing all the time ... and it appears for a few seconds only :(
2. wired connection on the old one works great (full speed provided by provider 50/50)

and, because the old one was a quite old (~10 years) so I decided to buy a new one, the *TP-LINK WR841ND*.

According to the reviews - it seemed great, BUT !!!

After I turn on the router, set it up the weirdest thing started to happen... the router is rapidly decreasing the speed of download and upload as well ... instead of 50/50 it's just about 0.8/20-30 which is ridiculous :) I do not mind the upload, but download is big headache for me.

I've tried almost everything - settings, default settings, factory reset, firmware is the newest one, .... I've tried to disable/enable everything, try almost all possible combinations in setup ...  nothing worked

Strange is, that wired connection is the same as WiFi connection ... both are cut to 0.8/20-30 ..

Do you have any idea what is going on here? Is there any way how to setup the router ?? Or do you have any idea how to fix the old one to show WiFi without dealing with the dropping ? Or have I bought just a crummy piece? And do I need to buy another one (I mean a different brand) ??

If you need more information, please let me know .. I will provide it

PS: speed was measured on speedtest[dot]net

Thank you guys

Comment: Although your replacement router is pretty low end, it has a good reputation for reliability and performance. I would try a factory reset first and test it with a wired connection, then wireless, then set it up. If that fails replace the router under warranty, and if that fails I propose the issue isn't the router at all.

Comment: i've already tried that .. factory reset.. even replacement in the store .. still the same .. problem must not be anywhere else .. cause with other router (at least wired connection) or w/o router  - it works ok ...

Comment: 2 routers are not going to be bad, it's possible, but the chances are astronomical. You say it works wired, meaning the internet connection and router software is good. That only leaves the radios, the "air" and your computer. The most likely case here is frequency congestion, severe interference, or defective hardware on the your wireless device.

Comment: no no ... I probably describe it incorrectly ... the old one works ok on wired only !! (but wifi dropped constantly)

the new one doesn't work even on wire

Comment: Old router worked, but wifi didn't, new router doesn't work at all? Did you try a different brand router? It isn't likely, but there is occasionally issues with specific brands interoperating between each other. But basic troubleshooting techniques are conflicting here, if you disconnect the patch cable from the router's WAN port and connect it directly to a PC's ethernet port, does it work properly? If it does and the wired router ports don't work there is something else going on and we need more details about the WAN port or something. Ethernet networks are logical, there is a reason.

Comment: right, old router worked but wifi is dropping... new router doesn't work at all ...

I do not have any other router... I am just about to buy new one (I was told to go with ASUS) ... when I plug cable from modem directly to PC (router is completely unplugged) - it works great ... something is wrong only when I use the NEW router ...

Comment: Fair enough, but since you replaced it at the store once, essentially testing with 2 different routers, there is likely a (rare) incompatibility between your ISP equipment and the router. Switching to another brand will likely be the solution, Asus makes a very good router, the RT-N66U is my go to budget gaming router, and for "cheap" the RT-N12.

Comment: thx will try that ... will definitely go with another brand :) hope they will have some (i am in philippines now :D ) ... incompatibility between ISP modem and the router was one of the possibilities I thought about ... but I just could not believe it .. thx will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I have found a solution ... the question was "incompatibility" between provider's modem and NEW router... so I've used old router (with disabled wifi) as a bridge between the modem and new router (wifi works great and wired connection as well) ... now, it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

From everything you have described, the problem is interference - ie someone else has set up an access point which is trying to use all the available bandwidth or another device (baby monitor, cordless phone, microwave are prime candidates) is spewing noise and killing the spectrum.

Unfortunately there is no simple answer to the problem.   You either need to track down the source of Interference and eliminate it - which can be quite hard, block the interference (again, quite hard) avoid using WIFI, or get a newer router which handles 802.11ac connections - and make sure your equipment also handles it.  (802.11ac works in the 5 gig rather then 2.4 gig band, which means that it is less prone to interference because its less used, has more spectrum and signals don't travel as far).   It also has an idea of using multiple antennas to cancel out interference and create "corridores" which increase performance.

I do note that there is a small possibility that another WIFI device is transmitting on the same / overlapping frequency with your router, in which case you can log into it and change the channel you are using.    If you have an android tablet/smartphone you can download a free App WIFI Analyser which can show you what channels quietest and you may be able to use those.

Comment: this is not a problem, since the wired connection is affected the same way ... if it was only wifi, it would be obvious .. :( but wired doesn't work properly too